# Sharing an $http object between controllers through a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app has two controllers, one fetches data from a database and the other controller uses the same data to draw a chart.

I would like to share the results between the two controllers in order not to run the query twice. I created a service for this purpose but the second controller does not get the result set object. If i do a console.log i get and empty object. If i wait 5 seconds and do a console.log I get results object. I think when the second controller fires, the results do not seem to be ready.

How can i transfer the results objects properly between the two controllers?

**My service**

```
app.service('chartData', function(){
    var qryResult = {};
    var addResult = function(newResult) {
        qryResult = newResult;
    };
    var getResult = function() {
        return qryResult;
    };
    return {
        addResult: addResult,
        getResult: getResult
    };
});
```

**First controller to get results**

```
app.controller('resultsController', function($http, $scope, chartData){
    $http.get('getresults.php').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.resultsList = data;
            chartData.addResult(data);
            console.log(chartData.getResult());
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
});
```

**Second controller to draw chart that currently gets an empty object**

```
app.controller('chrtCtrl', function($scope, chartData){

    console.log(chartData.getResult());

});
```

Thank you

Comment: "I think when the second controller fires, the results do not seem to be ready." - that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, since you are already using a service, have the service retrieve the data, instead of the controller getting the data and passing it to the service.

Second, you could use promises here, so `getResults` would return a promise that would be fulfilled when results are fetched.

```
app.factory("chartData", function($http){
    var getResultsPromise = null;

    return {
        getResults: function(){
            if (getResultsPromise) return getResultsPromise;

            getResultsPromise = $http.get('getresults.php');

            return getResultsPromise;
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in your controllers:

```
app.controller('resultsController', function($scope, chartData){
    chartData.getResults()
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.resultsList = data;
        });
});

app.controller('chrtCtrl', function($scope, chartData){

    chartData.getResult()
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

});
```

EDIT: here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Q4VXz64ydRU6goKiOYf)

Comment: will this mean everytime i call chartData.getResult() it will make an http call to getresults.php?

Comment: No, just the first time. The second time you would get an already generated promise.

Comment: @Patriot, I added a plunker that simulates $http request.

Comment: @New Dev, your api offers no mechanism for resetting the promise if you actually want to make a new request.  Once the results are retrieved you can't get a new set of results.  a reset or clear function on the api that deletes the promise would work, although there would be difficulty knowing when to call reset.

Comment: @SteveMitcham, of course, it's an example. You could check for inequality of input data to get a different promise, you could have `force` parameter to re-query. There a number of ways to tailor this to a specific use case.

Comment: Just wanted to get that in the conversation for people coming here with little knowledge about how promises actually worked.  My team went through a lot of pain learning promises when we transitioned to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the get function to do a broadcast when it has finished retrieving the data and then set the second controller to listen for the broadcast and then read the data off the service.

**service**

```
app.service('chartData', function(){
    var qryResult = {};
    var addResult = function(newResult) {
        qryResult = newResult;
    };
    var getResult = function() {
        return qryResult;
    };
    return {
        addResult: addResult,
        getResult: getResult
    };
});
```

**First controller to get results**

```
app.controller('resultsController', function($http, $scope, $rootScope, chartData){
    $http.get('getresults.php').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.resultsList = data;
            chartData.addResult(data);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('data-loaded');
            console.log(chartData.getResult());
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
});
```

**Second controller to draw chart that currently gets an empty object**

```
app.controller('chrtCtrl', function($scope, chartData){

    $scope.$on('data-loaded', function(){
          console.log(chartData.getResult());
    });

});
```